# AppDelegate.swift fetchRequest and managedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, swift3, ios10

I am facing problem I am using Swift 3.0.1 for data save in core data some text and image I am facing this error in my code

AppDelegate.swift file

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    setUpAppearance()

    return true
}



func setUpAppearance()
{
    let navStyle = UINavigationBar .appearance()
    navStyle.barTintColor = UIColor .orange
    navStyle.tintColor = UIColor .darkGray
    navStyle.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGray]

}
```

table View File code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    setUpAppearance()

    return true
}



func setUpAppearance()
{
    let navStyle = UINavigationBar .appearance()
    navStyle.barTintColor = UIColor .orange
    navStyle.tintColor = UIColor .darkGray
    navStyle.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGray]

}
```

any solution gives what I am doing......

Comment: Both codes are identical and there is no code related to Core Data saving at all

Comment: Also, **what error**?